# How do I find the max in an Array using only math algorithms, specifically I am trying to knock out the lowest number each time

Tags: javascript

The goal is to get the highest value in an array. I hope someone could walk me through where I went wrong with my code, and how I can get it to work.

What I am trying to accomplish is starting with a preset array, comparing `Arr[i]` and `Arr[i+1]`, then `Arr[i+1]` and `Arr[i+2]` and so on... pushing the highest value of each into an empty array called `Arrl`. Then set Arr equal to `Arrl`. Then calling the function back, and repeating until only `Arr[0]` is left and display the result.

This is the code I have so far:

```
var Arr=[10,56,76,98,82,45,98];
function largernumber(Arr){

var Arrl=[];
while (Arr.length>1);
for (i=0; i<Arr.length; i++){

    if(Arr[i]>Arr[i+1] || Arr[i]===Arr[i+1]){
        Arrl.push(Arr[i]);
    }
    else{
        ArrL.push(Arr[i+1]);
    }
    console.log(Arrl);  
}

for(var ar=0 ; ar<Arrl.length ; ar++){ 
    Arr[ar]=Arrl[ar];
    }
    return largernummber(Arr);
}
```

I am not great at describing so I will try to show what my plan is.
`var Arr=[10,56,76,98,82,45,98]`
(after each pass through the array length will decrease by one)

1st pass-through
`var Arr=[60,76,98,98,82,98]`
2nd
`var Arr=[76,98,98,98,98]`
3rd
`var Arr=[98,98,98,98]`
nth..
`var Arr=[98]`

Currently my logic is so flawed, its freezing the browser. oops... if possible I'd also love to see where I can place the console log to see each iteration.

Comment: Your code is freezing because once you start the `largernummber()` function you never get out of it.  It just 'recures' - returning itself again and again.

Comment: Thanks for editing the code! Couldn't figure out how. I am seeing the recurring now thanks!, Think my issue  now is, I cannot figure out how to replace the current Arr with the new values. it seems that each iteration just resets the Arr back to its original values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While all the other answers have pointed out perfectly correct and actually simpler solutions to your problem, I'm just "fixing" your code to use the algorithm that you've mentioned. I've avoided any changes to your code that are unnecessary.

Aside from typos in variable names, these are the issues with the code as it is:

1. `while (Arr.length > 1);` just loops forever. I assume it was an attempt to find the base case of the recursion. It should be `if (Arr.length === 1) return Arr[0];`, which says "if there is only one element left, that is the largest and return it".
2. When accessing `i + 1`th element in an array, always be careful about accessing the last element. In your case, your loop goes till `i < Arr.length` and `i + 1 === Arr.length` for the last iteration which results in `undefined`. Comparing numbers with `undefined` [won't work](https://javascript.info/comparison#an-incomparable-undefined). So make sure you loop till the last but one element, using `Arr.length - 1`.
3. Finally, you don't actually use the newly created array for the next leg of the recursion. You need to change `return largernumber(Arr);` to `return largernumber(Arrl);`

```js
var Arr = [10, 56, 76, 98, 82, 45, 98];

function largernumber(Arr) {
  var Arrl = [];
  if (Arr.length === 1) { return Arr[0] };
  for (i = 0; i < Arr.length - 1; i++) {

    if (Arr[i] > Arr[i + 1] || Arr[i] === Arr[i + 1]) {
      Arrl.push(Arr[i]);
    } else {
      Arrl.push(Arr[i + 1]);
    }
  }

  for (var ar = 0; ar < Arrl.length; ar++) {
    Arr[ar] = Arrl[ar];
  }
  return largernumber(Arrl);
}

console.log(largernumber(Arr));
```

As you might have noticed by now, point 1 and 3 point out the places where there is infinite recursion.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was going for! I was losing my mind over this and ended up using 5 "for" to get to the result haha. The comments are also greatly appreciated! Definitely learned from this experience!

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is getting the maximum number in the provided array then you can simply use `Math.max()` function for that. See below:

```js
const Arr = [10, 56, 76, 98, 82, 45, 98];
const max = Math.max.apply(null, Arr)
console.log(max)
```

And in the case that you want your code fixed then see below:

```js
const Arr = [10, 56, 76, 98, 82, 45, 98];

function largerNumber(Arr) {
  const maximums = [];
  
  // Base case
  if (Arr.length == 1) return Arr[0];
  
  // Note the use of Arr.length - 1 instead
  for (let i = 0; i < Arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (Arr[i] > Arr[i + 1] || Arr[i] === Arr[i + 1]) {
      maximums.push(Arr[i]);
    } else {
      maximums.push(Arr[i + 1]);
    }
  }

  for (let ar = 0; ar < maximums.length; ar++) {
    Arr[ar] = maximums[ar];
  }
  return largerNumber(maximums);
}

console.log(largerNumber(Arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max). Given a list of values it returns the max value.

```js
var Arr=[10,56,76,98,82,45,98]; 

console.log(Math.max(...Arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several alternatives.  The following code snippet uses the function `reduce` and thru a `Math.max` you can check for the greatest value.

```js
let arr = [10, 56, 76, 98, 82, 45, 98];
let max = arr.reduce((a, n) => Math.max(a, n), Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER);

console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

The in-build JavaScript `Math.max()` method can help you achieve your goal as it returns the, erm, maximum value of 2 or more numbers.

It can be used in conjunction with the `Array.reduce()` method, which applies a function to an array that compares or processes each item down to a single value or property....

```
var arr = [10,56,76,98,82,45,98];
var max = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
});
// max = 98
```

Alternatively you can `apply()` the `Math` function directly to the array...

```
var arr = [10,56,76,98,82,45,98];
var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
// max = 98
```

The `Array.reduce()` method can be useful in many different situations and on arrays which contain different kinds of data.  The `Math.max.apply()` method only works on arrays of numbers.

The in-built `Math.min()` method works exactly the same, but returns the lowest value of 2 or more numbers.

Hope that helps. ;)

See also:

- [Array.reduce @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Math.max @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)
- [Function.apply @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)